# php echo in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm quite new to html and php, I've tried a few things trying to achieve what i want but it never works.

It's a shopping cart, I'm trying to display data from mysql using php in a table, it would be simple if I didn't have other elements that I want to display in the table as well ($value and $sub) which aren't stored in mysql but are calculations.

When I don't try to display it in a table it all works perfectly, and when I add the table I can only get the 'name' to display in the table, If I try to include anything else it fails.

Code below displays 'name' under the table name column, next thing to display would be '$value' under quantity and so on (haven't added anymore columns yet)

```
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id_product, name, price FROM elec_guit WHERE id_product='.($id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;

?>

<div class="table">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

<?php                   echo '<td>' .$get_row['name']. '</td>' .$value. ' @ &dollar;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). ' = &dollar;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'" >[Delete]</a><br />';
            }
        }
        $total += $sub;

    }
}
?>


    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: first thing your table tag should be out side the loop, it will mess the layout and  will create table again and again.

Comment: Yes, the opening table tag needs to come before the start of the loop. Also, Every piece of data inside your table should be inside of `<td>...</td>` tags which are themselves inside of `<tr>...</tr>` tags. If you have two columns in your table then each table row (`<tr>...</tr>`) should contain exactly two `<td>...</td>` elements.  In your echo statement you have some data that is not inside of a `<td>` element. You cannot have text in a table that is not inside of a `<td>` element. Fix this and you'll be fine. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp to try out some table examples.

Comment: One easy way to see what is actually going on is to open your page in a web browser and select "view source" to see the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible code to render column and row properly.

```
<div class="table">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>

foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id_product, name, price FROM elec_guit WHERE id_product='.($id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;

?>


    <tr>

<?php                   echo '<td>' .$get_row['name']. '</td>' .$value. ' @ &dollar;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). ' = &dollar;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'" >[Delete]</a><br />';
            }
        }
        $total += $sub;

    }
}
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Thanks for the tip, changed it to your advice and still works correctly, although I'm still not sure how to display anything after the 'name'.

Comment: if you want to display anything beside name, you need to create new column with <td> tag, if you want to display anything after name than you need to insert it name column itself, i am adding another answer to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the table outside of your loop, that will fix a majority of your problems. Another issue is you only had one `<td>` wrapping the name column in your while loop, but you didn't have a `<td>` wrapping the other information in that row, so I wrapped that.

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>

            <?php
            foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
                if ($value>0) {
                    if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
                        $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                        $get = mysql_query('SELECT id_product, name, price FROM elec_guit WHERE id_product='.($id));
                        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                            $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                            echo '<tr><td>' . $get_row['name']. '</td>' .
                                 '<td>' . $value. ' @ &dollar;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). 
                                 ' = &dollar;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a>'
                                 '<a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'" >[Delete]</a></td></tr>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome that did it! I knew that I only had one <td> added in my while loop, I didn't have any more added because it didn't work with more than that first one, it was the full stop after each </td> that I was missing and what ultimately solved it. Thanks! @Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Added new code as per your comment.

```
    <div class="table">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>

foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id_product, name, price FROM elec_guit WHERE id_product='.($id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;

?>


    <tr>

<?php                   echo '<td>' .$get_row['name']. $value. ' @ &dollar;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). ' = &dollar;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'" >[Delete]</a><br /></td> </tr>';
            }
        }
        $total += $sub;

    }
}
?>



</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing i want to tell you is `mysql_*` is officially deprecated as of `PHP 5.5`. And removed entirely as of `PHP 7.0`. So please dont use it.**

Refer : http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

For `mysqli_*` : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Now about you code :

You are using `table` tag inside the loop. This will generate multiple tables. Try out this code :

```
<div class="table">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query("SELECT id_product, name, price FROM elec_guit WHERE id_product='$id'");
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;


echo '<tr><td>' . $get_row['name']. '</td>' .
'<td>' . $value. ' @ &dollar;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2). 
' = &dollar;'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a>'
 '<a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'" >[Delete]</a></td></tr>';
            }
        }
        $total += $sub;

    }
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information I'll be sure to read up and update :)

Comment: And what about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>

<?php   
        foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id_product, name, price FROM elec_guit WHERE id_product='.($id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $get_row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value;?> @ &dollar;<?php echo number_format($get_row['price'], 2); ?> = &dollar;<?php echo number_format($sub, 2); ?> <a href="cart.php?remove=<?php echo $id; ?>">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add=<?php echo $id; ?>">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete=<?php echo $id; ?>" >[Delete]</a><br /></td>
    </tr>
        <?php   }
        }
        $total += $sub;
        
    }
}
?>
    </table>
</div>
```